# Tweepy ( Twitter ) change to exists_friendship -> lookup_friendship ( Python )

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

It used to be that you could get a True False from exists_friendship with Tweepy through the Twitter API but you now have to use lookup_friendships due to changes last year (which has a 15 per 15 min rate limit I think?)... how would I amend this python code (that used to work) to reflect that and make use of the new function?

It's for a local community/neighbourhood app I just want it to check if someone is following the authenticated user or not.

user_id is the person you want to check if they are following you (already defined earlier in the script)...

00000000000 is your own user_id/the app user's id... but this [Tweepy link](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py#L473-L475) seems to suggest you just use 'self'?

```
    if api.exists_friendship(user_id, 00000000000):
        print 'YAY! Friend!'
    else:
        print 'Boooo!'
```

N.B. Tweepy is [here](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py#L473-L475)

N.B. Needless to say, this does not work:

```
if api.lookup_friendships(user_id, 00000000000):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it turns out that the right request with Tweepy is as follows:

```
user_id = '00000000000'
print api.show_friendship(target_id=user_id)
```

That returns JSON for the relationship between the authenticated user and the other user, within which is 'followed_by' that has a True/False value.